# How to solve run time error?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Ideone{
    //start 10:10 pm

    public static List<point> pointArray = new ArrayList<point>(10);
    public static TreeMap<Integer, point> pointMap = new TreeMap<Integer, point>();

    public static void main(String[] args){



         point p1 = new point(-2, -1);
         point p2 = new point(0,2);
         point p3 = new point(1,3);
         point p4 = new point(3,6);
         point p5 = new point(7,8);
         point p6 = new point(0,6);
         point p7 = new point(1,8);

         //Ideone.addSegment(p1);
         Ideone.addSegment(p2);
         Ideone.addSegment(p3);
         //Ideone.addSegment(p4);
         //Ideone.addSegment(p5);
         //Ideone.addSegment(p6);
         //Ideone.addSegment(p7);

         Ideone.findMaxSegment();
    }

    public static class point{
        private static int start;
        private static int end;

        public point(int start, int end){
            start = this.start;
            end = this.end;
        }

        public static void setStart(int start){
            point.start = start;            
        }

        public static void setEnd(int end){
            point.end = end;
        }
    }

    public static void addSegment(point given){
        //An array of points. 
       int len = 0;

        // if the given point doesn't become part of existing point, add as new element
        for(int i = 0; i < pointArray.size(); i++){
            point temp = pointArray.get(i);
            if((given.end >= temp.start) && (given.end <= temp.end)){

                temp.setStart(given.start);   
                len = temp.end - temp.start;
                System.out.println(temp.start+ " " + temp.end);
                pointMap.put(len, temp);
            }else if( given.start >= temp.end && given.start >= temp.start){
                temp.setEnd(given.end);
                len = temp.end - temp.start;
                pointMap.put(len, temp);
                System.out.println(temp.start+ " " + temp.end);
            }else{
                if(pointArray.get(i) == null){
                    point newPoint = new point(given.start,given.end);
                    pointArray.add(newPoint);
                    len = given.end - given.start;
                    pointMap.put(len, newPoint);
                    System.out.println(given.start+ " " + given.end);
                }    
            }
        }
        //else extend the point.
    }

    public static void findMaxSegment(){
        point maxLengthPoint = pointMap.lastEntry().getValue();
        System.out.println(maxLengthPoint.start + " " +  maxLengthPoint.end + " " + pointMap.lastEntry().getKey());
    }

}
```

The above code is to for the following problem : Starting and ending co-ordinates of one-dimensional line segments are given. Find the co-ordinates of longest line segment that can be formed from these segments. Write two functions addSegment() and findMaxSegment().

I am getting error as

Runtime error

Comment: Look into variable scope.

Comment: Couldn't get you. Could you please explain more. How to fix it?

Comment: You're declaring `pointArray` and `pointMap` in main so it is not recognized in the scope of the method.

Comment: I mean search for the terms `variable scope`.

Comment: @user3167973 if my answer is helpful you can select my answer below down arrow in my answer click on write sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Ideone{
  // declare it above outside main method
    private static ArrayList<point> pointArray;
    private static ArrayList<point> pointMap;
```

rest of your code.......

and some you have write

```
for(int i = 0; i < pointArray.size(); i++){
            point temp = pointArray[i];//wrong
```

this is wrong since you are trying to get element from arrayList

```
point temp = pointArray.get(i);//use get method to fetch elements from ArrayList
```

and this statement is also wrong

```
pointMap.add(len, temp);//wrong
```

it should be

```
pointMap.put(len, temp);//use put method to insert element in Hashmap
```

and also

```
public static void findMaxSegment(){
        point maxLengthPoint = pointMap.lastEntry();// this is also wrong since there is no method name lastEntry in map
        System.out.println(maxLengthPoint.start + " " +  maxLengthPoint.end + " " + maxLengthPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the variables are declared inside `main`, they are only visible inside `main`. Move the declarations out of `main` and into the class itself:

```
class Ideone {

    private static ArrayList<point> pointArray = new ArrayList<point>(10);
    private static Map<Integer, point> pointMap = new TreeMap<Integer, point>();


    public static void main(String[] args){
        ...
```

Comment: It worked. After fixing that I get runtime error. Could you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You declared both `pointArray` and `pointMap` in the main method. They are only available within that method (the scope of the method). You can declare them as an instance variable so they will be available to all methods of the class by declareing them outside of the main method.

```
class Ideone {
    private static ArrayList<point> pointArray = new ArrayList<point>(10);
    private static Map<Integer, point> pointMap = new TreeMap<Integer, point>();

    //Methods and stuffs ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keep these two out side of your main method

```
private static ArrayList<point> pointArray = new ArrayList<point>(10);
Map<Integer, point> pointMap = new TreeMap<Integer, point>();
```

and use.. this for accessing it

```
   for(int i = 0; i < Ideone.pointArray.size(); i++){
```

and for accessing map you need to instantiate Ideone class like this

```
Ideone ideon=new Ideone();
ideon.pointMap.put(len, temp);//
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining the variables:

```
pointArray
pointMap
```

in the main method, which means that you can only use them in that method unless you pass it to another function or object. The best solution is to define them as instance variables so something like:

```
class Ideone{
    //start 10:10 pm
    private static ArrayList<point> pointArray;
    private static ArrayList<point> pointMap;
    // Rest of code
```